# bit data type inside derby DB (created in NetBeans)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby, netbeans-7

i created a Derby DB table from within Netbeans 7.1, using the 'create table' window inside the IDE.  one of the columns need to be of a bit type (i want to hold boolean data - 1/0).  when i added that column, i used 'char for bit data' as its type.  when i add lines using the IDE's 'insert records' window, the lines are added, but when i try to add lines using SQL commands (which how i'll eventually add data to the table from within my java code), it always throws an error. if i try `INSERT INTO APP.TEMP (ID, BOOL) VALUES (3, 0)` the response is `Columns of type 'CHAR () FOR BIT DATA' cannot hold values of type 'INTEGER'.` and if i try `INSERT INTO APP.TEMP (ID, BOOL) VALUES (3, '0')` the response is `Columns of type 'CHAR () FOR BIT DATA' cannot hold values of type 'CHAR'.`
i thought to overpass is by creating the table with SQL code (`CREATE TABLE...`), and set that column simply as 'bit', but when i do so the response i get is `Syntax error: Encountered "bit" at line 7, column 8.`

so how can i have a boolean field in a Derby DB?  or should i give up and simply use integer?

cheers,
eRez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Derby has an actual BOOLEAN datatype, if that's what you're looking for: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/rrefsqljBoolean.html

Comment: thank, but how come when i try this - CREATE TABLE Games
(
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
white_player_id int NOT NULL,
black_player_id int NOT NULL,
winner_id int,
active boolean NOT NULL,
start_date timestamp NOT NULL,
end_date timestamp
) i get an error - 'Syntax error: BOOLEAN'

Comment: could it be because i'm using Derby 10.2?  i read that only from version 10.7 the boolean is supported.  if so - i do i upgrade it?

Comment: Yes, Derby 10.2 is VERY old. Upgrading is easy; here's how: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/devguide/cdevupgrades.html